# Не могу получить текст элемента

Tags: jquery

Есть элемент li

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По нажатию на него, я хочу получить текст, т.е. "2"

Однако переменная page - пустая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

P.S. Я думаю это не важно, но элемент li добавляется динамически...

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контекст кода, который находится непосредственно в атрибуте `onclick` - элемент, чей атрибут. Но когда Вы вызываете там функцию `clicki()`, это происходит в глобальном контексте. Так что `this` внутри функции - это `window`.

Передавайте элемент в функцию как параметр:

```js
function clicki(el) {
  var page = $(el).text();
  console.log(page);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li onclick="clicki(this)">1</li>
  <li onclick="clicki(this)">2</li>
  <li onclick="clicki(this)">3</li>
</ul>
```

или используйте `Function.prototype.call`:

```js
function clicki() {
  var page = $(this).text();
  console.log(page);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li onclick="clicki.call(this)">1</li>
  <li onclick="clicki.call(this)">2</li>
  <li onclick="clicki.call(this)">3</li>
</ul>
```